# How to integrate Spring 4 with Apache Tiles 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4, apache-tiles, tiles-3

I am using Spring framework version 4 and I get confused which folder to put the XML files, specially the tile definitions and where to find the resolver bean.

Comment: Please add relevant tags when you asking the question, It is very helpful to add peoples attraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles) should explain all this for you.

Answer (score 5):

The tile definition xml is specified when you define the `TilesConfigurer` bean. If you are using Java-based configuration this would look like:

```
@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml"});
    tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
    return tilesConfigurer;
}
```

If you are using xml-based configuration this would look like:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When you specify `/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml`, you are telling the `TilesConfigurer` to look for all tiles definitions recursively under the `/Web-INF/views` directory.

Answer (score 5):

you need to configure your servlet-context with couple of beans, make tiles.xml to use layout template and rest of the definitions in views.xml to derive the base definition in tiles.xml:

```
  <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass">
        <beans:value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="order" value="0"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: You can also use the TilesViewResolver instead of the UrlBasedViewResolver (```<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"/>```). You don't need to configure the viewClass then.